# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_.contains) karma test

Tags: angularjs, npm, phantomjs, underscore.js, lodash

When running my karma tests, I get this error on the jenkins build. So to make it clear, this works fine locally and all my tests pass, but when I run the exact same code on the jenkins box, I get the error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) VisitDataSpec #emailExists should return true if email is already FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_.contains(visitEmails,email)')
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/src/app/model/VisitData.js:9
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/test/app/model/VisitData.spec.js:208
```

I'm smelling buggy version of phantomjs. The version on the server is 1.9.0. I downgraded my version locally to the same version to try to reproduce the problem locally and that doesn't happen.

I already tried to include both underscore and lodash and none of the libraries work.

I get the same error in a test where Restangular tries to use underscore as well:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) EmailVisitControllerSpec #signIn should call VisitService to add a new service with scope data FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_.contains(safeMethods, operation.toLowerCase())')
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js:21
        at elemFunction (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js:1217)
        at wrapper (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js:3949)
        at postFunction (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js:1246)
        at apply (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js:402)
        at wrapper (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js:4254)
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/src/app/rest/VisitService.js:9
        at invoke (/home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/node_modules/karma-sinon-chai/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:2583)
        at addVisit (:1)
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/src/app/visits/EmailVisitController.js:9
        at /home/server/jenkins/workspace/Reception UI Build/test/app/visits/EmailVisitController.spec.js:91
```

Using angular 1.4.2, angular-mocks 1.4.2, mocha 2.3.4 and right now, underscore 1.8.3 or lodash 3.10.1 (tried with either).

By the way, this may be relevant: I'm having four of these when building on Jenkins:

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
```

Maybe it's not resolving some of the dependencies, but unfortunately I can't see which ones. Using npm 3.3.2.

Does anyone have any thoughts about what I'm missing here? Any known incompatible versions?

Comment: I have same issue here - did u find solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: lodash 4.x. Moved back to 3.10.1 and all works fine.

Comment: I'm actually using 3.10.1 already. Also tried with underscore instead of lodash and it didn't work either.

Comment: I was also using 3.10.1 but my CI updated that to 4.X. I just added lodash#3.10.1 to my bower.json. Hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

so yeah, restangular has this line inside:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "lodash": ">=1.3.0"
  },
```

lodash just recently upgraded to version 4.0 so now when you install restangular it will download newest version of lodash

to solve this problem just add lodash in version 3.10.1 your dependencies (npm or bower):

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "restangular": "1.5.1",
    ...
    "lodash": "3.10.1"
  }
```

Comment: It didn't really work for me. Anyway, it seems restangular is not supported by the developer anymore, so I stopped using it.